# Org-mode table cells fontification

Tags: emacs, highlight, org-mode

Is there some way to make org-table cells appear in different face than 'org-table face without putting any marks, tokens etc into cells?

For example I would like to see `foo`, `bar`, `1` and `2` appear in different face than `|`'s and `-`'s without altering contents of these cells, e.g. change `foo` to `*foo*`.

```
| foo | bar |
|-----+-----|
| 1   | 2   |
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not currently possible.

Comment: Apparently, saying "No" count as a useless answer.  Weird.